# In cypress how to test if we have reached the last slide

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I have multiple slideshow files with different number of slides. For example some have 10 and some have 80 slides. I want to test every slide. So to navigate, there are forward and backward arrow buttons. I'm simply clicking the forward button and testing every slide:

```
for(let n = 0; n < 80; n ++) {
    cy.get('#forward').click();
    // Test code..
}
```

The problem with this is even in slideshow with 10 slides it's clicking forward button 80 times. Is there a way for cypress to know that it has reached to the end and stops early?

The slideshow also has a slider at the bottom which shows the current page number. So one way might be that it checks when the page number stopped changing and it ends the test.

Another approach might be that cypress drags the slider to the end and then it goes backward on slides so test stops when it reaches page 1. So any way to drag slider to the end?

Comment: There are some examples of moving a slider, but how you do it depends on what kind of slider you have. What application framework are you using?

Comment: @user16695029 I use this code to move the slider: `cy.get('.slider').type("{rightarrow}{rightarrow}")`. I want to know if I can just send it to the end at once. It's React Material-UI Slider component.

Comment: @user16695029 I've found a way: `cy.get('.slider').type('{rightarrow}'.repeat(80), { delay: 0 })`. This just sends the slider to end of the slide. If you have a better solution, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drag slider to the end we can use

```
cy.get('.slider').type('{rightarrow}'.repeat(80), { delay: 0 })
```

Then note down the last page number and go back that many times

```
cy.get('.slider').then(($page) => {
    const pagenum = $page.text() // makes note of current page that .slider is on

    for(let n = 0; n < pagenum; n ++) {
        cy.get('#backward').click();
        // Test code..
    }
})
```